# Question about eigenvalue and invertibility problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, determinant

I found a post with a question like this:
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387071/let-lambda-be-an-eigenvalue-of-a-prove-that-lambda-1-is-an-eigenvalu)

> Assume A is invertible, Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Prove that $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

The answer goes:

> given that $A$ is invertible, $Ax=\lambda x$, $A$ is invertible, and $\lambda\neq 0$, we have
>   $$Ax=\lambda x\implies A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}\lambda x\implies x=\lambda A^{-1}x\implies \frac1\lambda x=A^{-1}x.$$

My question is why are we assuimg $\lambda \neq 0$. And for a $\lambda \neq 0$, can we always claim that it has an inverse?

Comment: If $\lambda =0$ them $\lambda^{-1}$ does not exist ; otherwise it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume $\lambda \neq 0$ since $A$ is invertible if and only if $0$ is no eigenvalue of $A$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3553485/529121) question for more details.

If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\lambda$ always has a multiplicative inverse in the corresponding field, so $1/\lambda$ exists.